# How to test singletons in one test class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, singleton

I want to test the behavior of a singleton class with following methods:

```
public class SomeSingleton
{
    private final static int DEFAULT_VALUE1 = ...;
    private final static int DEFAULT_VALUE2 = ...;

    private static SomeSingleton instance;

    public static void init(int value1, int value2)
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("SomeSingleton already initialized");
        }

        instance = new SomeSingleton(value1, value2);
    }

    public static getInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            init(DEFAULT_VALUE1, DEFAULT_VALUE2);
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

And then I have a test class with several test methods, which invoke `init` several times:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(SomeSingleton.class)
public class SomeSingletonTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetInstanceSunnyDay()
    {
        [...]
        SomeSingleton.init(...);
        [...]
        SomeSingleton.getInstance();
        [...]
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetInstanceRainyDay()
    {
        [...]
        SomeSingleton.init(...); // IllegalStateException
        [...]
        SomeSingleton.getInstance();
        [...]
    }
}
```

When I do it this way, I always get the `IllegalStateException` in the second test because `instance != null`.

How can I run several tests involving `init` in one test class?

Putting `testGetInstanceSunnyDay` and `testGetInstanceRainyDay` in 2 separate classes solves the problem, but I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: What benefits do you suppose a singleton offers here that, say, an immutable class wouldn't?

Comment: The singleton is part of an old code base. I didn't write it. For now, I just want to capture the behavior of that legacy code in unit tests. And then gradually improve the design of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I agree with Jon, the other option is to use [ReflectionTestUtils](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/util/ReflectionTestUtils.html) or reflection in general to set the `instance` field to `null`. Knowing that this can be brittle if the field name changes.

Answer (score 5):

Fundamentally singletons are hard to test, precisely because of this sort of thing. You *could* add a `clearStateForTesting` method:

```
static void clearStateForTesting() {
    instance = null;
}
```

... but I'd *suggest* that you avoid the singleton pattern in the first place, if possible.

Also note that your singleton implementation isn't thread-safe at the moment. There are significantly better implementations if you *really* need to use a singleton.

Comment: Another similar option would be to use reflection to set the `instance` field to `null`.

Comment: @JohnB: Indeed - I try to avoid using reflection in tests where possible though.

Comment: Agree. Sucky tradeoff between using reflection which is brittle and adding a method to the class that is for testing reasons only. Either way not great. Cheers.

Comment: @JohnB From my subjective point of view, reflection is the best option in this case. Please submit your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko: Do you want your tests to break if you change the private field name? That sounds *very* brittle to me. But hey, I would try to avoid the singleton to start with :) Note that the presence of a "only present for testing" method makes it *really clear* to anyone reading the code just what's required to test this code. It would also be more reusable if other code *using* the singleton needs to test different configurations.

Comment: I can't avoid the singleton right now, since that's legacy code and I can't refactor the entire code base fast. The purpose of the test is to capture current behavior of that legacy code. It's not a problem when a test fails due to a renamed field.

Comment: There should be no stigma attached to changes just to make testing easier/possible. I do it all the time. Admittedly this is normally a question of how the code is *designed*, but a few methods here and there (with package-private access) is quite fine for testing. I think Mr Skeet is right here.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it is a Singleton, the `init` method makes no sense as a public method. Make it `private` and use only `getInstance` in your unit tests.